# Look for value of dictionaries in a list without loop over the list

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, search

I am new to Python and I need some help here.
I need to search a number in dictionary in a list.
I have a long list that looks like this:
`userinfo= [{"username": "root", "uid": 0, "try": {"P0000": 100}}, {"username": "Jack", "uid": 1, "try": {"P0000": 100}}, {"username": "Mike", "uid": 3, "try": {"P0000": 100}}, {"username": "Helen", "uid": 7, "try": {"P0000": 100}} ... ]`
(the uid is ordered)And I want to know if there is some way that I can search for a uid that equals to some integer, (say 200 for example) without loop over the whole list.

The only way I can search for a 'uid' is to iterate through the whole list to see if there is some uid that equals to the integer and stop if you find a uid larger than the integer or find a uid equal to it. But this is too slow. Or would it be of help if I choose binary search?
Thank you very much if you could help.

Comment: reshape the list into a dictionary with a key of the uid and values of the full dictionaries. If you don't want to do that, you might create a companion dictionary that acts as an index with keys of uid and values of the index into the current array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Using list comprehension to search for specific id and filtering values which are empty i.e., `''`.

```
search_id = 3
val = list(filter(None, [value if value['uid'] == search_id else '' for value in userinfo]))
print(val)
```

**Output**

```
[{'username': 'Mike', 'uid': 3, 'try': {'P0000': 100}}]
```